# Invoke AWS CLI based on param value from a JSON file using jq

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-ssm

I have a JSON file which contains some parameter name and their values. The values are path to `AWS` SSM param store. I want to create another JSON file from the source file which will basically contain the actual values from param store based on the path.
eg:
source.json

```
{
  "redis":{
    "cluster":{
        "host":"{host_param_name}",
        "port":"21",
        "username":"{user_param_name}",
        "password":"{password_param_name}"
    },
    "cluster2":{
        "host":"{host_param_name}",
        "port":"21",
        "username":"{user_param_name}",
        "password":"{password_param_name}"
    }
  }
}
```

target.json

```
{
  "redis":{
    "cluster":{
        "host":"localhost",
        "port":"21",
        "username":"temp",
        "password":"temp"
    },
    "cluster2":{
        "host":"localhost",
        "port":"21",
        "username":"test",
        "password":"temp"
    }

  }

}
```

So, here in this case I want to call `aws ssm get-parameters --names <name>` for each param_name present inside the value field (for host, username and password) and replace them in the target.json file.

I can do it by reading individual params and creating this. But is there any elegant way where we can basically iterate each field using `jq` and then call `aws ssm` command and replaces the value.
`jq` version: `1.5`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would write a small Node.js or Python script rather than wrestle with bash and a dozen CLI invocations.

Comment: Can the aws commands be issued independently of source.json?